# two dimension session issue with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to store two dimensional array in session, where i keep creating the array through a function call.

I am trying with this code

```
function nextQuestion($questionId,$response)
{ 
       $this->session->set_userdata("res[$questionId][]"),$response);
}
```

but this is not creating a two dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key stored in the session must be a string but the value can be a multi dimensional array.
You can retrieve the array, manipulate it and save it in the session again like this:

```
$session_response = $this->session->userdata("res");
//some manipulation on $session_response
$this->session->set_userdata('res', $session_response);
```

Answer (score 1):

sametimes codeigniter session library can be boring.
if i add array to session, i serialize the array.

You can serialize array and get back with unserialize. or you can use php session library.