# CodeIgniter set multidimantional session value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set a value in a Codeigniter session array, something like:

```
$this->session->userdata['xxx']['yyy'] = $some_value;
```

But it didn't work. Also, I've tried:

```
$this->session->sess_write();
```

But that did not work either for me. Does anyone know how I can assign a value to this kind of session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [two dimension session issue with codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763557/two-dimension-session-issue-with-codeigniter)

Comment: Did you try putting your second code snippet directly after your first in one try?

Comment: Did you check the given solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can set multi-dimensional array as below.

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array("index_1"=>array("val1","val2","val3")));
```

Then you can use

```
$sess_data =  $this->session->userdata("index_1");

echo $sess_data[0];
echo $sess_data[1];
echo $sess_data[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set multi dimensional array with this example.

```
$row => array(
        'basket_id'=>'1',
        'order_id'=>'1',
        'cus_id'=>$cusid,
        'product_id'=>$pro_id,
        'bas_quantity'=>1
)
$cart = array($row);
$this->session->set_userdata('cart',$cart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly unset specific value of multidimensional array in session of codeingiter. You have to take all session value to variable. Unset the specific value and again set the variable in session as shown below:

```
$items_session = $this->session->userdata('item_names');
unset($items_session[$key][$app_no]);
$this->session->set_userdata('item_names',$items_session);
```

Hope this will help.